# Can Send only email with random characters from Android phone using Gmail

Tags: android, email, android-intent

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 i.setType("message/rfc822");
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , sb.toString());
 try {
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
 } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
 Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.",      
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

The sb.toString() is a stringbuilder that holds the appropriate data.

At first, I thought everything working fine because I could open the email app and the appropriate text was displayed. However, after pressing send I found that when I looked at the mail in my gmail client (on phone and on computer) it was gibberish. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

I am using gmail mail client.

Here is what I see in the email after I send it to myself:

```
&#0      &#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;4&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;07,497,552&#0;&#0;&#0;
```

repeated many, many times.

Before I press send, I see: integer, integer, integer
 on each line for a 50-75 lines.

Comment: hmm,,I am using the same code and it is working fine. Which client are you choosing to send the mail? or maybe it's because you are providing not enough capacity for the content when using StringBuilder.

Comment: do i need to provide capacity to string builder? In case it matters the string builder is taken in 13 bytes of data at a time from a sensor (accelerometer). I was/am worried that this has something to do with having to use bytes and converting to a string (and vice versa).

Comment: If you are just using default SB constructor, it does not really matter. As you mentioned, it might be a type conversion error. If you are getting bytes array from a sensor, why don't you just use String class?

Comment: I solved the problem. Silly me. It was reading in data from bluetooth. But it wasn't reading filling it out the entire byte array. I think this was what was causing the problem. I am now just reading and writing a byte at a time, and (at least) it's working.